# Adding shape of defined dimensions using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, geometry, measurements

I am attempting to add a feature with defined geometry as a layer. Having added the feature I checked on the dimensions of its sides and they measure differently.

This is the code that I am using.

```
x = [0,0,-5000,-5000,0,0]
y = [0,-1000,-1000,1000,1000,0]

vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString?crs=epsg:7405", "temp", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields() 

PointList = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    p = QgsPointXY(x[i],y[i])
    PointList.append(p)

geom_line=QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(PointList)
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(geom_line)
pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

The lines do not measure as 2000m and 5000m, but as 1997m and 4992m (although opposite sides do not measure the same).

I wonder if it is to do with the CRS or the measure tool? I think that I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 3 uses **ellipsoid length calculations** by default whereas in previous versions, this was ignored and instead *planimetric distance calculations* were used. If you measure the lines using the expression:

```
length($geometry)
```

You should get the values you were looking for (5000m and 2000m):

[image: Field calculator]

---

Before you use your code, set your project ellipsoid measurement to `None / Planimetric` and then run your code again. You can set this from the menubar:

```
Project > Properties > General > Measurements
```

[image: Project properties]

You could just use the expression

```
$length
```

And you should get the same values as mentioned above (5000m and 2000m).