# Adding shape of defined dimensions in metres on an WGS84 ellipsoid using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

How can I place the shape of defined dimensions (in metres, 5000m X 2000m) measured around the WGS84 ellipsoid at a location on the ellipsoid (51 degrees N 2 degrees W)?

Joseph provided a very thorough answer to a previous question (link below) clarifying how QGiS makes measurements. This helped me to form this question.
[Adding shape of defined dimensions using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325685/adding-shape-of-defined-dimensions-using-pyqgis-in-qgis-3-4/325700#325700)

Comment: The concept of "dimensions" breaks down in angular units. How many vertices do you intend to use to describe a rectangle? If it's just five, then you have a spheroidal trapezoid.

Comment: By converting the data/map into British National Grid and then adding the coordinate grid. Or maybe a WGS84 UTM zone. You'll then get the linear measurements you want.